# Angular 1.5 Encoding/Decoding Special Characters in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
 <p class="form-control-static col-sm-7"><a target="_blank" ng-href='/app.html#/playout-search?air_date={{dc.info.air_date}}&market={{dc.info.market}}&syscode={{dc.info.syscode}}&network={{dc.info.network}}&spot_uuid={{dc.info.spot_uuid}}'>{{dc.info.spot_uuid}}</a></p>
```

Which with data looks like this

```
<p class="form-control-static col-sm-7"><a target="_blank" ng-href='/app.html#/playout-search?air_date=2017-05-24&market=BOST&syscode=8369&network=TRAV-HD&spot_uuid=NZEKpL33iE+UDpqixAVtmg%3D%3D'</a></p>
```

My issue is that when the user clicks on the link and gets redirected the URL the '+' signs get converted into '%20'

```
/app.html#/playout-search?air_date=2017-05-24&market=BOST&syscode=8369&network=TRAV-HD&spot_uuid=NZEKpL33iE%20UDpqixAVtmg%3D%3D
```

Making the user unable to see the correct data, any input will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `decodeURIComponent()` method of JavaScript.
So inside your HTML get the href dynamically:

```
<p class="form-control-static col-sm-7"><a target="_blank" ng-href="{{getMyHREF();}}">{{dc.info.spot_uuid}}</a></p>
```

And inside your controller define that function and return that value:

```
$scope.getMyHREF = function() {
  return decodeURIComponent(MYCOMPOSEDHREFHERE);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and when I click on the link it doesn't return the URL, the redirect looks like this /dc.getMyHREF() with a 404 returning

Comment: sorry add {{ }}. Updating the answer